# Can Mousehover points a preview of the files in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

​We have a requirement which displays file name with its extension This file has to be shown in a popup as placed mouse hover on it.For example in a GridView the more number of Parent files, when we place a pointer on the parent file, it shows a preview of the "Child files" also. can we have a possible in Asp.net Mvc. please give me any solution.

Comment: what you want to show on hover give that value to the title attribute of or ow where ever required.

Comment: Hi vinay, give me any example regarding this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzobc4tb/ hover on sample div text

Comment: Thanks Vinay, for giving solution reply immediately.

Comment: but if we come to give the hover to entire grid, like that the above example is possible, can u please give me the solution.